# Cant print the error message in console from object

Tags: xcode, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I receive the following object error:

```
 "error": {
 "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

I'd like to call an action when the error code is 401 or message is "Invalid Credentials" but the following code does nothing and when I try do `console.error("got something:", err["code"]);` to log in the console it comes blank:

```
  console.error("got something:", err["code"]);

        if (err["code"]=="401") {
          console.log("Found error: 401");
          this.messageServ.presentMessage("auth_error");
    }
        return err;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your not access fields deep enough in your object graph

Try this:

```
 err["error"]["code"]
```

Comment: I received this when I try to do it like that : TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'err["error"]["code"]')

Comment: post console.log(err) object.  What you have has a dangle } so maybe there is more nestedness.